# Styling a child element in a third-party component

Tags: styled-components

I'm using a 3rd party component named "Dialog" with the render method below.  As you can see - the component has more than one className.  I'd like to create a styled-component called StyledDialog which contains a prop that lets me override the width associated with the div that has the "SURFACE" className.  Can this be done with Styled-Components - or do I need to bring the source code into my app and handle that manually.

```
render() {
  const { className, children, onClose, open, ...otherProps } = this.props;
  const ariaHiddenProp = open ? {} : { 'aria-hidden': true };

  return (
    <aside
      className={classnames(
        ROOT, 
        {
          [ANIMATING]: this.state.animating,
          [OPEN]: open,
        }, 
        className
      )}
      onClick={(e) => { 
        if (onClose) onClose(e); 
      }}
      onTransitionEnd={() => { 
        this.setState({ animating: false }); 
      }}
      {...ariaHiddenProp}
    >
      <div
        className={SURFACE}
        onClick={(e) => { 
          e.stopPropagation(); 
        }}
        {...otherProps}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
      <div className={BACKDROP} />
    </aside>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanation, i think you should wrap this 3rd party component with `styled` method and apply your styles by referencing the corresponding classnames of that component from the wrapped styled component.

For instance, If the name of existing component is `Hello`, you can apply styling from a `styled-component` on any of its DOM children like this:

```
const StyledHello = styled(Hello)`
    .${classes.SURFACE} {
        width: 10rem;
        border: 2px solid green;
    }
`;
```

[**Working Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/kx92jnqwk5)